# Mysql in PHPMYADMIN need to display name next to count total

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get a list of policynames and the number of quotes that they have shown as a summary beside them

I have managed to get a total of each policyname, but the policyname does not show beside the total.  Here is what I have done:

```
SELECT COUNT( PolicyName_PolicyNameID )
```

FROM quotes
WHERE `Policytype_PolicyTypeID` = '1'
GROUP BY `PolicyName_PolicyNameID`
LIMIT 1 , 1000

I just want it to also show the Policyname next to the  count total? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

`SELECT`PolicyName_PolicyNameID`, COUNT( PolicyName_PolicyNameID )
FROM quotes
WHERE`Policytype_PolicyTypeID`= '1'
GROUP BY`PolicyName_PolicyNameID